# Tcl: How to get namespace and procedures of calling namespace?

Tags: tcl

I have some generic procedure. I would like this procedure to be able to get the name of the namespace and names of the procedures within the namespace where this procedure is called.

I have tried following code:

```
proc register {} {
    puts [info procs]
    puts [namespace current]
}

namespace eval Foo {
    proc bar {} {
        puts bar
    }

    proc _baz {} {
        puts baz
    }

    register
}
```

However, this prints results for the namespace where `register` is defined, not for the namespace where it is executed. It looks like there are no dedicated commands for these tasks or at least these are not `info` or `namespace` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get information about the calling context, use [`uplevel`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/uplevel.html):

```
proc register {} {
    puts [uplevel 1 [list info procs]]
    puts [uplevel 1 [list namespace current]]
}
```

Comment: Why is `list` actually needed in this case?

Comment: To correctly form/format the argument. If you are confident of your formatting you can also do `"info procs"` instead of `[list info procs]` but using `[list]` is good habit to have to prepare you for more complicated cases like `"info \"$cmd\""` etc.

Comment: In this case, they're actually equivalent (they compile to identical bytecode). But in general, using `list` to form commands to evaluate in other contexts is *extremely* highly recommended; it handles all the awkward cases you don't normally think of.